# Hamburger in the oven

Tags: baking

Can you bake hamburger in the oven? Is it safe? I am trying to make tater tot casserole and always have baked my hamburger in the oven with it is that not a good thing to do?

Comment: Why do you think it's not safe? Are you cooking it thoroughly to the appropriate temperature?

Comment: well after all I have read it seems like everyone cooks their hamburger before just didn't know if I should....

Comment: Have you heard of meat loaf?

Answer (score 6):

As long as the hamburger is actually getting cooked through, you're safe.

But in a casserole-style bake, that may be a bit tricky, so you want to be certain that you're checking the temperature of it before you serve. You want the beef to reach the [safe temperature of 160F](https://www.foodsafety.gov/keep/charts/mintemp.html). Think of something like a meatloaf... they're definitely cooked in the oven, not on the stovetop, but you need to reach a safe internal temperature or risk foodborn illness.

My guess is that most recipes call for cooking the meat first because when you brown the meat in a skillet, you'll develop some flavors in it through the process of the [maillard reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maillard_reaction) that give a more complex flavor. In baking the entire thing from raw, you will only achieve this browning on the surface of the casserole, whereas when you brown the meat first, you get it throughout.

Additionally, when you brown it first, you're able to cook off a lot of the moisture and grease (if you're using a high-fat percentage beef), which might otherwise make your tater tots soggy or very greasy. So, if you haven't, I'd recommend giving a version that uses browned meat a try first to see if you like the outcome.

Comment: And along with the moisture, fat. If your ground meat isn't very lean, then you could end up with a really greasy casserole if you don't cook and drain first.

Comment: When making ground beef dishes such as meatloaf, meatballs, Salisbury steak, etc. the addition of bread crumbs serves to soak up that moisture from the run off. This is also why you should let these dishes 'rest' before serving, some of those juices will be 'reabsorbed' into the meat as the dish is left to cool for 10-15 minutes before serving.